# UTC and local timezones in Ruby

Tags: ruby, timezone

I am located in the Eastern Time (ET) timezone. It is 4 hours behind UTC time. UTC is the standard by which the world regulates clocks and time. I am using Mac OSX.

I was reading this particular [article](https://nandovieira.com/working-with-dates-on-ruby-on-rails). It seems to suggest that Ruby uses UTC by default if the `TZ` environment variable is not set. And he gives an example:

```
ENV["TZ"]
#=> nil

Time.now
#=> 2015-12-08 10:30:00 -0200

ENV["TZ"] = "America/Los_Angeles"
#=> "America/Los_Angeles"

Time.now
#=> 2015-12-08 04:30:14 -0800
```

Once the environment variable is set, Ruby will then use that timezone. So I tried it in `irb`:

```
ENV["TZ"]
 => nil 
Time.now
 => 2018-03-29 16:30:21 -0400
ENV["TZ"] = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
 => "Eastern Time (US & Canada)" 
Time.now
 => 2018-03-29 20:30:40 +0000
```

Right now it is a little after 4:30pm or 16:30 in military time. So actually when the TZ environment variable was NOT set, it gave the local time, not UTC time. And after I set the variable to my timezone, it gave a completely wrong time. Why do I not get UTC time when environment variable is not set and why do I get the wrong time when I set the environment variable to my timezone?

Comment: `2018-03-29 20:30:40 +0000` is not the wrong time. It is the UTC equivalent of `2018-03-29 16:30:40 -0400`. Also, the article doesn't suggest that when `ENV["TZ"]` is not set, `Time.now` will be reported in UTC time. In the example you quote, time is reported in a time zone that is -0200 different from UTC (presumably that is the time zone of the local computer running the example).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is incorrect. Ruby will pick up the time zone from your computer rather than use UTC by default.

As for why

```
ENV["TZ"] = 'Eastern Time (US & Canada)'
```

didn't change the time to eastern is because the right way to do it is:

```
ENV["TZ"] = 'US/Eastern'
```

---

When the value in `ENV["TZ"]` is not `nil`, but is not recognized, Ruby defaults to `UTC`:

```
Time.now.zone # => "EEST"

ENV["TZ"] = 'Some gibberish'
Time.now.zone # => "UTC"

ENV["TZ"] = 'US/Eastern'
Time.now.zone # => "EDT"
```

Comment: It apparently gets the time from /etc/localtime: $ ls -l /etc/localtime
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  36 Nov 30  2016 /etc/localtime -> /usr/share/zoneinfo/America/New_York